# write_rich_text of xlwt returns error

Tags: xlwt

I am using xlwt and the following code returns the error `Worksheet object has no attribute write_rich_text` Why would that be?

```
seg1 = ("NOT ", Font1)

seg2 = (str(data['Customer'])[:-1], Font2)

sheet1.write_rich_text(row, 4, (seg1, seg2) , Style1)
```

Note: I am using xlwt 0.7.5 and I see write_rich_text() defined in worksheet.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you initializing your `sheet1` variable?

Make sure there is a page first:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
sheet1.write_rich_text(....)
```

Also you want to take into consideration that `write_rich_text` is not included in all versions of `xlwt` so you might want to make sure that the version of `xlwt` that you are using is the same version that you verified that actually has `write_rich_text`.  Clearly the version that is imported into your app doesn't know anything about a `write_rich_text` method.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code so that we can see what is happening.  According to the error you have a `Worksheet` object that doesn't have the `write_rich_text` method so maybe something strange happened to your `Worksheet` object but we can't see the workflow (how you initialized the variable, what other methods were called, etc).

Comment: I updated my answer.  It's possible that you have two versions of `xlwt` on your system and your app is importing the version that doesn't have the `write_rich_text` method (which is likely due to the error message and since earlier versions of `xlwt` don't have that method).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Max for the pointer. Yes, I had an older version of xlwt in python27 that didn't have write_rich_text method. Replacing that xlwt with the newer version fixed the issue.